# How to make sure users cant change other users resources with JWT + Auth0

Tags: jwt, authorization, auth0

So i have an app that will have multiple users, i need auth to make sure users cant change other users resources

What i do is i put `userId` in `sub` of a user's access token

API endpoints where users can change their resources looks like this `/v1/todo/post/:userId`

In my "validate jwt" middleware, after validating the access token, i check if `userId` in `sub` matches the `userId` in the request uri

But then, if i decide to apply this change, i would need to design every endpoint on my API so it has `userId` as a request

What is usually the approach here?

Comment: "would need to design every endpoint on my API so it has userId as a request". Well, if every endpoint pertains to one user only, what is the problem with this?

Comment: thats fair, thanks